# Sequence defined by recursive formula and floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Can someone help with this question:

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,...$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $a_0=1$ and $a_n=a_\left\lfloor{\frac{7n}{9}}\right \rfloor + a_\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{9}}\right\rfloor$ for $n=1,2,...$

Prove that there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $a_k < \frac{k}{2001!}$.

I tried using proof by contradiction by assuming $a_n<\frac{n}{2001!}$ for all $n\geq0$, but I could not arrive at a contradiction. I also examined the function's rate of change and it seems like this function has a "lower complexity" than a linear function i.e. the function has a smaller rate of change than a linear function $a_n=kn$ for some positive value $k$, but I could not find a proof for this.

I also tried finding the general term, but I could not figure out how to simplify the recursive formula.

Comment: Related https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h378183p2089128. It was a problem $13$ in [Baltic Way Mathematical Olympiad 2001](https://imomath.com/othercomp/Bw/BwMC2001.pdf)

Comment: Could you explain how they obtained "If $n\ge 9^m*5$, then $a_n\le (\frac 89)^mn$"

Comment: @pblpbl: By induction on $n$. Suppose that $a_n\le\left(\frac89\right)^mn$ when $n\ge 5\cdot9^m$, and suppose that $n\ge 5\cdot 9^{m+1}$. Then $\left\lfloor\frac{7n}9\right\rfloor\ge 35\cdot 9^m>5\cdot 9^m$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{n}9\right\rfloor\ge 5\cdot 9^m$, so $$\begin{align*}a_n&\le\left(\frac89\right)^m\left(\left\lfloor\frac{7n}9\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}9\right\rfloor\right)\\&\le\left(\frac89\right)^m\left(\frac{7n}9+\frac{n}9\right)\\&=\left(\frac89\right)^{m+1}n\,.\end{align*}$$